# S3 browser upload original filename metadata encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

- Given I use AWS S3 browser upload
- When I upload File with name `;aoeu^'eaus%+eau90#ن:西eee.jpg`
- Then "${filename}" Metadata returned by S3 message is `"=?UTF-8?Q?;aoeu^'eaus%+eau90#=D9=86:=E8=A5=BFeee.jpg?="`

How can I decode this string to original filename (ideally with native Ruby solution)?

Comment: 1) What device are you using to look at the metadata?  2) What is the encoding of that device? 3) What is the encoding of the original filename?

Comment: It's not a device it's AWS S3 Browser Upload http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html  that is sending message via AWS SQS https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/ and my Application is fetching this message. AWS S3 has built in "${filename}" metadata header that will translate to original filename in AWS SQS message. The original file was created in Ubuntu 15.04 Nautilus so I guess UTF-8